# How should I handle response types for services that dynamically call endpoints?

Tags: typescript

As I am converting my project from .js to .ts, I am finding a lot of objects with dynamic properties that are used by various services.

For example,

I have a service which makes api calls to various endpoints and returns the response.  These endpoints all a collection of items under different keys, and some have additional properties (like boolean flags, available user actions, etc)

So this looks something like:

```
interface ApiParams {
  page: number,
  sort: 'asc' | 'desc',
}

interface ApiConfig {
  responseKey: string,
  call: (params: ApiParams) => Promise<any>,
  params: ApiParams,
}

# in my service:

makeCall (config: ApiConfig) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    config.call(config.params).then((response: Response) => {
      res(Presenter.present(response[config.responseKey]));
    });
  });
}
```

As soon as I get to dealing with typing the `Response` type, I feel like I can easily get derailed by exhaustively having to specify every single key / value type that these api endpoints return...  But, instead I have gone the lazy route of just doing something like:

```
interface ResponseCollectionItem {
}

interface Response {
    [ index: string ] : any | ResponseCollectionItem[],
}
```

Is there any problem with going this route?  Are there patterns for how to manage this sort of dynamic stuff?

Comment: Does each endpoint have a consistent response type?

Comment: no.  each endpoints has its own unique response data.  That's why the config has a responseKey property.

Answer (score 0):

For each API its a good practice to be able to find what all the parameters are. If you have 5 or more APIs in a project it's really easy to confuse them, forget them, etc. So the extra work of defining them all now pays off in saving you headaches later.

I might not totally be understanding your goal, so here are two options that could maybe help

To reduce the extra code, you could use extend types/classes if there's common information

```
class TypicalResponse {
    // responseKey: string,
    // call: (params: T) => Promise<U>,
    // params: T,
}

const UserResponse extends TypicalResponse{
    userEndpoint: "/users",
    //Has everything in TypicalResponse
    //And also a userEndpoint field
}
```

or use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```js
interface ApiConfig<T, U> {
    responseKey: string,
    call: (params: T) => Promise<U>,
    params: T,
}

function makeCall<T,U>(config: ApiConfig<T,U>) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        config.call(config.params).then((response) => {
            res(console.log(response));
        });
    });
}

interface UserApiParams {
    id: number,
}
interface UserApiResponse {
    name: string,
}
const UserApi: ApiConfig<UserApiParams, UserApiResponse> = {
    responseKey: "users",
    call(params: UserApiParams): Promise<UserApiResponse> {
        return new Promise<UserApiResponse>(
            (resolve, reject) => {
                resolve({name: "hi"})
            });
    },
    params: {
        id: 1,
    },
}


makeCall(UserApi);
```